# Detect articles missing from a table of contents (toc.yml) file in DocFx

Tags: markdown, docfx

Sorry if this is an easy solution and I'm not aware.

Assuming source files are in a directory like this...

- Docs/articles/guide-1/article-1.md
- Docs/articles/guide-1/article-2.md
- Docs/articles/guide-1/article-3.md
- Docs/articles/guide-1/article-4.md
- Docs/articles/guide-1/article-5.md
- Docs/articles/guide-1/toc.yml

...and toc.yml looks like this:

```
 - name: Article 1
   href: article-1.md
 - name: Article 2
   href: article-2.md
 - name: Article 3
   href: article-3.md
```

Is there a way to see that article-4.md and article-5.md are in the same directory as toc.yml but not referenced in the file?

I know of [scripts that identify image files that are un-referenced in a directory of Markdown files](https://gist.github.com/sugarmo/8470598). I hope to accomplish roughly the same thing with un-referenced Markdown files.

Thank you if anyone knows how to do this, or has a suggestion on what I might pursue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have discovered now that one way is built in to DocFx. You can generate PDFs with an attribute of `generatesAppendices` as `true`. This produces a document called `appendices` in the directory the PDFs are output. It shows all files not linked up to a TOC. Add the `.pdf` extension.

[Documentation](https://dotnet.github.io/docfx/tutorial/docfx.exe_user_manual.html#33-properties-for-pdf)

Example usage in docfx.json:

```
    "template": [
      "pdf.default",
    ],
    "keepRawFiles": false,
    "generatesAppendices": "true",
```